# OData Services and client side query parsing for Entity Framework

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, entity-framework, odata

We use Entity Framework in our product but the database is installed alongside the software for each of our clients.  To expose this data I have built a "publish/subscribe-ish" model WCF web service that uses shared sessions to allow the desktop client to notify the service it is available and ready to distribute data.  At which point the thinner clients such as mobile apps or web applications can request the data using a unique id / password combination to identify the desktop client (and ultimately its database) it wants data from.

As it stands the web service is very rigid as I'm sure you can imagine; having taken the traditional service operation for each required data set approach.

I would like to replace the current web service with an OData Service for obvious reasons however because the databases are outside the local network of the web service the straight forward WCF DS + EF isn't going to work.

**Using ODataLib or WCF Data Services would it be possible to create a data service that merely forwards the request uri and allows a desktop client to parse the query into something Entity Framework understands?** If so how would I handle the OData query to EF/SQL on the desktop client side of things. The functionality that does this seems to be deep within the API and tucked away within WCF Data Services (not even sure it exists in ODataLib)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question. I'm actually a bit confused by what you want the desktop client to do with the OData request. But I'll throw this out as something that might give you further ideas. If you already have a full, thick desktop application that includes a client-side install of a database, then consider this. If the desktop app were a Lightswitch app talking to a local database, all on the client, then behind the scenes Lightswitch wires up an OData service that serves as the pipeline between the client presentation layer and the database. And this OData service is directly accessible (if 'EnableClientAccess' is set to true).
In other words, the client desktop app talks to an OData service which talks to the database using EF if you so choose, and gives the user the full visual experience, translating user actions into OData requests. The same OData endpoint, as a standalone service,  would talk to the same database and expose the same data functionality as the client, and so, by default, the OData requests are also translated into the same EF actions.

Comment: In order to achieve this I would need a way of discovering the data service since we can't know ahead of time what the endpoint for the data service will be.  Is this something that could be done via talking to a known web service that uses a callback to grab the endpoint? I imagine the reply from such a call to be 

http://public-ip-address/service/{uniqueid}

Comment: such a web service might take an auth token so clients can only reach the data service end-point by going through the web service in which the thick client's register themselves with.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your setup. You have a thick desktop client with a database on a customer PC. The customer can query the database from a mobile device by talking to the desktop client. To do so, it queries a public web service to get the endpoint that the desktop is listening on? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Well, I've read your alternate description [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22960480/458354)  (You shouldn't post the same question twice). Quick question...how does the desktop listen for thin clients if your customers are not hosting? Self-hosted WCF? Is the assumption that the thin client is on the same intranet as the desktop?

Comment: Yeah, I apologise for that.  I've implemented a shared session web service in which the thin clients share the same session with a full thick client (specified by a unique id) the web service merely forwards calls into it via a callback contract the thick client implements.  It is not he best approach IMO but the best I have at the moment.  The web service itself is hosted by us using IIS and no the thin clients are able to communicate over the internet.

Comment: So maybe that's what I'm getting at...let's say your web service just gave your thin client the endpoint...without forwarding any queries or anything....could the client talk to the desktop directly?

Comment: It could if we had our clients host the OData service, though I'm not sure what that would truly mean, is it possible to have a webservice return the endpoint of another webservice via callback?

Comment: I'm not sure about the endpoint from callbacks. What i was getting at was that if the desktop hosts the OData service, and uses it to talk to the database, then your thin client can do the same, and you dont have to worry about the "translation" of odata requests to EF/SQL...which is what i was hoping to encourage you to avoid. As far as the "endpoint lookup service" you are describing, I was imagining you were either storing the actual endpoints either dynamically or statically, and correlating them to the uid/pwd calls from the thin clients...not sure...

Comment: It sounded like your desktop was registering itself with the 'lookup' service...so, does it not know its own endpoint? I guess I was assuming that was the point of 'registering'...telling the service what endpoint it was listening on, with a key, and when the thin client calls the lookup service with that same key, the lookup service gives it the registered endpoint? did i get that wrong?

Comment: The thick client does not know its own end point, it implements a callback, the endpoint of that callback must be known internally via the `OperationContext` that is persisted in memory for each thick client since this is what is used to call upon the desktop client. The problem is being able to surface this endpoint known by the `OperationContext` so that I can return it to the calling thin client.  I believe all I would need is the public ip of the network the thick client is on but I feel there may be more to it than that.

Comment: I've worked with OperationContext in WCF, so I know 'what' you are talking about, but I don't have any specific insight to that part of your question. I zeroed in on trying to prevent you from re-inventing an odata-to-sql parser by using the odata as the common api to both thick and thin clients. Sorry if I missed the heart of your question. I'm going to bow out of the conversation. Dont accept my answer, so that hopefully someone with better insight will see this question as unanswered and pick it up.